# kaminari-bootstrap conflicts with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, activeadmin, kaminari

My rails project utilizes Twitter Bootstrap for the main site's look and feel. In order to make kaminari fit in a bit better, I added the kaminari-bootstrap gem.  So far, so good.

The problem is that the kaminari-bootstrap HTML breaks the pagination in active_admin.

The ideal thing would be to find a way to only enable kaminari-bootstrap for the main site, and not for active admin.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it helpful, in your `application.css` remove your `active_admin.css` . then restart your server.

write in your `active_admin.css.scss` file -

```
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

and then try

Comment: The problem with that is that it removes all styling from active admin itself.